# Is there a way to create Table in Java AWT?

Tags: java, database, awt

Is there way to create Table in Java AWT? I need to create simple Java AWT program for insert, edit, delete and read users from database.

Comment: I would consider using Swing which is an extension of AWT. It has JTable which might do what you want.

Comment: Yes i know that but it need to be in AWT, or is there any other way to display data from database in AWT ?

Comment: *"it need to be in AWT"* it need to be explained (why you won't join us in the 3rd millennium).

Comment: simple.. i need to create the program in AWT, without SWING components

Comment: If you don't want to use swing then create your own table, use a bunch of labels and a scroll pane. (This is pretty much doing the exact same thing as swing, so why not use swing?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes: Make your own table with a bunch of labels as cells, and a scroll pane. You can set it up to add more cells/labels on the fly, and add any features you want.

If you cannot or do not want to do the above, then you can seek out a third party library that creates tables for AWT.

Or take the much easier and faster option and just use swing.

Answer (score 0):

you can make table in swing JTable. But now you should use Graphics:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class name extends Frame{
 name(){
  setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  setSize(1000,1000);
  setVisible(true);
}//end of name()
public void paint(Graphics g){//opening graphics
  g.drawRect(10,50,100,100);//make a rectangle 
  g.drawRect(50,50,100,100);//another rectangle
  g.drawRect(10,100,100,100);//and another
  g.drawRect(50,100,100,100);//last rectangle
  g.drawString("SOMTHING", 30,80);//write a text in a rectangle
}//end of graphics
public static void main(String[] args){
  name n=new name();
}
}//end of Frame
```

Comment: NOTE: I just write codes : how make table in awt. these may not help you for database

Answer (score 0):

You can create using a Panel with GridLayout, with the components (Labels or TextFields) and then you can place that panel inside your frame. Here is the example code! Hope this will work!

But the only problem is, we cannot set the size for the components which we placed in a GridLayout! Anyone knows how to set the size of the component in GridLayout, please leave a comment!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
public class AwtTable extends Frame{

    AwtTable(){
        
        Panel p = new Panel();
        Color c = new Color(241, 216, 252);
        
        try {
            
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database","root","password");
            
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from table_name;");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
            TextField l1 =null,l2=null,l3=null,l4=null,l5=null,l6=null ;
            int row=1;
            while(rs.next()) {
                
                l1 = new TextField();
                l1.setText(rs.getString(1));
                l2 = new TextField();
                l2.setText(rs.getString(2));
                l3 = new TextField();
                l3.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(3)));
                l4 = new TextField();
                l4.setText(rs.getString(4));
                l5 = new TextField();
                l5.setText(rs.getString(5));
                l6 = new TextField();
                l6.setText(Long.toString(rs.getLong(6)));
                
                Button add = new Button("Edit");
                Button delete = new Button("Delete");   
                add.setSize(70,20);
                delete.setSize(70,20);

                p.add(l1);p.add(l2);p.add(l3);p.add(l4);p.add(l5);p.add(l6);
                p.add(add);p.add(delete);
                p.setLayout(new GridLayout(row,8));
                row++;
            }
            p.setBackground(Color.white);
            p.setBounds(100,100,1000,400);
            add(p);
            
            setLayout(null);
            setVisible(true);
            setSize(700,500);
            setTitle("Employee Datas");
            setBackground(c);
            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }   
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AwtTable at = new AwtTable();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a question, please create a new one.